# Adjugate of a matrix product of rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $n>m$. Define $$H:=A^\top D B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}.$$
Is it possible to write adjugate of $H$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $D$? We known that for square matrices it holds $\operatorname{adj}(AB)=\operatorname{adj}(B)\operatorname{adj}(A)$, does there exist something for rectangular matrices? All the matrices are full-rank.

Comment: How much do you know about exterior algebra? The clearest answer would be $\wedge^k\left(AB\right) = \left(\wedge^k A\right) \left(\wedge^k B\right)$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$ (for which $AB$ is well-defined) and any nonnegative integer $k$. This generalizes both the Cauchy-Binet formula and a formula for $\operatorname{adj}\left(AB\right)$ (since $\operatorname{adj} U$ for an $n\times n$-matrix $U$ is just a matrix representing the linear map $\wedge^{n-1} U$ in an appropriate basis).